# OpenGL ES 2.0 glVertexAttribPointer - Caching Redundant Calls

Tags: android, c++, ios, opengl-es

I was profiling my iOS and Android application and realised that there was a lot of redundant glVertexAttribPointer calls per frame. I came up with a strategy to cache these states and only call the method when required.

I figured that glVertexAttribPointer only needs to be called when the following occurs:

- The attribute has not yet been set
- A new shader is bound (Possibly invalidating the attribute locations)
- The vertex declaration changes (Possibly invalidating the offset or type)

Unsurprisingly after testing this there were no redundant glVertexAttribPointer calls. However there must be a flaw in my logic as the rendering no longer works correctly. I figured that my cache strategy is too zealous and I'm not re-calling glVertexAttribPointer as often as I should be. I then tried invalidating the cache whenever our materials change (i.e. whenever the render state changes). This fixed the rendering but the redundant calls returned (although fewer than before).

Am I on the correct track with my initial caching strategy and can anyone help me identify the other situations in which the cache should be invalidated?

Comment: You might try sprinkle in calls to `glGetVertexAttribPointerv` before setting the attrib pointer anew. This way, you should be able to identify where the pointer goes astray.

Comment: Surely the function should only be called if any of its params have changed. glVertexAttribPointer(AttribLocation (Changes if the shader changed), size, type, normalised, stride, offsetPtr (change if the vertex declaration changes))